# Split vector by zeros

Tags: vectors, splitting-field

I have got a problem with splitting a vector by zeros.

I have a vector for example 
$$v=[1\ 3\ 2\ 6\ 4\ 0\ 0\ 2\ 4\ 6\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 3\ 1]$$

I need to get vectors like
$$v_1=[1\ 3\ 2\ 6\ 4]$$

$$v_2=[2\ 4\ 6]$$

$$v_3=[3\ 1]$$

Is there any way to do this?

Of course I don't know of how many vectors are included in main vector $v$ and how many zeros delimits vectors.

Comment: I think you'll have to define accurately what does "splitting a vector by zeros" mean. In your example, there're lots of possible splittings if no further information is given.

Comment: @Timbuc I don't know what you exactly mean by defining it more accurately. I think it is defined good enough. I have some unknown vector, but I know that there are zeros which delimits the inner vectors. Maybe there are many possible solutions but result is only one. My brother can do it in C simply but want to do it in some very easy way in MATLAB. NOTE: i'm not a programmer and also not a professional in MATLAB so I need some easy way that I can understand.

Comment: If I'm guessing correctly then, you split the vector everytime there're zeros in it? So $\;(1,0,0,1)\;,\;\;(1,0,1)\;$ give both the same split $\;(1)\,,\,\,(1)\;$ ?

Comment: @Timbuc Yes you guess right. That's what I exactly want. I found some function SplitVec which was created by some user. I found it on some forum, it has some subfunctions but I don't understand it as well even if I read a commentars for that. As I said I'm not pro in MATLAB.

Comment: You didn't mention\tagged at first anything here about programs. This question is then better suit for some other site about programming, I believe.

Comment: @Timbuc I thought by mistake that this site is also about MAATLAB. You think I should post this question to StackOverflow?

Comment: Oh, dear: not at all, @Jan ! That site is for *mathematics* research level. Choose one of the suiting sites in exchange. There's a site for Mathematica and other for Programmers

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using zero blocks of any length as delimiters. A simple way to do this using computer code would skip any initial zeros, then keep track of the nonzero terms so far, building a temporary vector of increasing length, and when/if another zero is encountered that temp vector gets "split off" and you start again. Of course if you are on a nonzero entry at the "end of file" that final temp vector gets split off as the last one.

I don't know of any common mathematical construct which would do the splitting you want.

Comment: I know the process but I need some functions of matlab to do this. I already found a function A = strsplit(str,delimiter). But I don't have a string I have a vector. So I searched for conversion function, I found just S = char(V) but after this and A = strsplit(s,'0') it crashed.

Comment: @JanAntl Sorry to say I don't know details of MATLAB operations etc. Maybe this question would be better at one of the sites devoted to computer code or programming...